# Fill canvas before alert

Tags: javascript, canvas, alert, fill

For a canvas game, how can I load a canvas fill and text before the window alert? Even by just a few milliseconds.

There is a collision that occurs between two players.
Immediately after, the canvas should fill as colour and text should be displayed.

The problem is the alert appears before this happens.

The alert, when OK pressed, should reload the page - I have found that setTimeout does not work because of the `location.reload` inside of it.

Quick (nasty) example of how it works currently: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajrwpmb3/3/)

```js
//collision
if (x < object.x - 50 + 60 &&
    x + width > object.x - 50 && 
    y < object.y - 60 + 60 && 
    height + y > object.y - 60) {

  
//fill before alert
ctx.fillRect(0,0,2000,2000);
ctx.strokeText("You only reached a score of " + score + ", you lose!\nPress 'OK' to try again?", 250, 290);
ctx.fillText("You only reached a score of " + score + ", you lose!\nPress 'OK' to try again?",250,290);

  
//end game alert
if(!alert("You reached a score of ...")){
location.reload();
}}
```

Comment: Don't put an alert function call inside an if condition statement...

Comment: @evolutionxbox, by removing the alert from within the if condition and changing to `alert("You only reached a score of " + score + ", you lose!\nPress 'OK' to try again?") 
location.reload(); `, I still need the fill/text to load before alert. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the if condition to check the score, and then call the alert inside the true or false block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
var x = 1 //collision or any true statement
if (x == 1) {
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
  ctx.strokeText("You only reached a score of ...", 250, 290);
  ctx.fillText("You only reached a score of ...", 250, 290);
  setTimeout(function(){
      alert("You only reached a score of ...");
      location.reload();
  }, 10);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajrwpmb3/10/

Alerts does not return any value. they block the complete code execution. The problem here was that browsers tend to do bulk updates to DOM for changes done inside a function. Since in your code changes to canvas as done and immediately browser thread is blocked by alert, therefore the changes are not applied. in my example i have added 10 ms to break the event of canvas update and alert into 2 blocks in browser's event queue, this allows browser to complete event 1 i.e. canvas update first and then execute 2nd event i.e. show alert which blocks the code. 
You can validate this concept by using the timeout value as 0ms.

Comment: In case you need to as user to continue/cancel the reload of game, you should use "confirm" box, it will return true/false based on the selected button.

Answer (score 3):

> setTimeout perfectly works, check this code out

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="buttonID">click here</button>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
var my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,170);
my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"#7E6189");
my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"#FFFFFF");
ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.font="30px Verdana";
var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,0);
gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
//irrelevant above



var x = 1 //collision or any true statement


// when the event occures
// create the gredient
document.querySelector('#buttonID').onclick = function() {
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,2000,2000);
  ctx.strokeText("You only reached a score of ...", 250, 290);
  ctx.fillText("You only reached a score of ...",250,290);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(!alert("You only reached a score of ...")){
        location.reload();
    }
  }, 300); // chenge the millis to whatever you want
}
```

> i am using an event to execute the code because the permanent alets are annoying

Comment: #buttonID is just a button to execute the code whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

### window.alert, confirm, and prompt should die..

So many answers but I will add one more.

**DON'T USE ALERTS**... ever... please!!!, for the sake of all the users of your site and because if they are like me the very first time I see an alert on a site I turn them off. The fact that users can block/stop these alerts should be more than reason enough to not use them, because relying on alerts will break your game for pedantic people like me.

**A much better Alert**

Your best option is to create your own non blocking, customized alert. Create a `div` set its style to `position: absolute`, center it to the page, then add an `ok` button and hide the whole thing.

Give the alert div the `id="myAlert"` and when you need it just unhide it and wait for the button to be clicked, when the button is clicked hide the alert.

For your game you should add some pause logic, and when the alert needs to be shown just pause the game and show the alert. When the alert has been clicked unpause the games and do what is needed.

The demo just shows how you can implement a simple custom alert and pause a game.

```js
// alert function handles the display of a custom alert
var alert = (function(){
    var firstRun = true;
    var callback;
    function alertCallback(){  // handle the click event
        if(typeof callback === "function"){
            callback();
        }
        myAlert.className = "alert hideAlert";
    }
    function alert(message,callbackO){
        myAletMessage.textContent = message;
        myAlert.className = "alert showAlert";
        if(firstRun){
            firstRun = false;
            myAlertButton.addEventListener("click",alertCallback)
        }
        callback = callbackO;  // set the callback
        
    }
    return alert;
})()

var canvas,ctx;
function addCanvas(){
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.top = "0px";
    canvas.style.left = "0px";
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
function resizeCanvas(){
    if(canvas === undefined){
        addCanvas();
    }
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.font = "32px arial black";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
}

resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas);



// The following code just shows a pretend game with a paused function 
// The paused is used when the alert is called.

var paused = false;
var x,y,t;



function update2(timer){

    globalTime = timer;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    if(paused){
        if(t > 0){
            var sc = t / 10 + 0.1;
            ctx.setTransform(sc,0,0,sc,x,y);
            ctx.fillText("BANG!",0,0);
        }
        var sc = Math.sin(timer /100) * 0.1 + 1.0;
        ctx.fillStyle = "Green";
        ctx.setTransform(sc,0,0,sc,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
        ctx.fillText("Paused!",0,0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
    }else{
        if(t > 0){
            var sc = t / 10 + 0.1;
            ctx.setTransform(sc,0,0,sc,x,y);
            ctx.fillText("BANG!",0,0);
            t -= 1;
        }else{
            if(Math.random() < 0.1){
                x = (Math.random() * (canvas.width -200))+100;
                y = (Math.random() * (canvas.height -200))+100;
                t= 10;
            }
        }
        if(Math.random() < 0.01){
            alert("A 1 in 100 random event paused the game!",function(){paused = false;});
            paused = true;
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update2);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update2);
```

```css
    
.alert {  
    position : absolute;
    z-index : 100;
    left : 35%;
    width : 30%;
    top : 10%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;    
}
.hideAlert {
    display : none;
}
.showAlert {
    display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert hideAlert" id="myAlert">
    <div id="myAletMessage"></div><br>
    <input id="myAlertButton" type="button" value="OK got it."></input>
</div>
```